# java tcp messaging not working but .net version does

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send json messages to a specific ip and port using tcp socket connections. The code seems to work with the initial connection and message submission but when checking the destination server, I do not find the messages. I have a .NET version that runs as well and for some reason trying to send the exact same message works fine. I tried to use wireshark to capture the packet and connection but it seems there is no packets being set at all.

wireshark capture:

[image: wireshark]

The code in java :

```
  try

    {



        clientSocket = new Socket(ipaddress, portnumber);
        outStreamSplunk = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        outStreamSplunk.flush();
        clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);


        outStreamSplunk.println(post + "\n");
        System.out.println("SENT MESSAGE: " + post);
        clientSocket.close();

    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
         modifiedSentence = "";
    }
```

and the code in .NET that works:

```
    ip = "xxx.xxx.x.xxx"
    port = xxxx


    Dim ips As String = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).AddressList(0).ToString()
    _GLOIP = IPAddress.Parse(ips)
    _port = port

    'initiate the client and get the stream to use
    myTcp = initiate()
    netStream = myTcp.GetStream() 

Try

        If netStream.CanWrite Then
            If Not text.EndsWith(vbCr & vbLf) Then
                text += Environment.NewLine
            End If

            Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)
            netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

        Else
            err = "cannot write to the stream"
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        appLogs.constructLog(err & vbNewLine & ex.Message.ToString, True, True)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

EDIT:

I tried another server as I thought it may be my machine and since the .NET script runs on another machine. Turns out the TCP connection works fine but not sure how to interpret the response:

[image: tcp response]

I dont see any errors so perhaps its a problem with the destination server. The only other difference between the .NET version and java version is that the.NET version is writing into byte array. This has me stumped. But if I don't find resolution I will need to do it the hard way and use the .NET version and transfer message somehow from main java code to the .NEt version.

Comment: That is not a good exception handler...

Comment: The difference is in the exception handlers... In the .Net version, you are logging the error. In the Java version, you are ignoring it. Add at least a `exc.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Also, the .Net code does not cover establishing a connection in the first place.  Since you see no packets going out over the wire in the Java version, it seems likely that that's where your problem lies.  At a guess, `ipaddress` or `portnumber` is invalid, so that no connection is even attempted (since Wireshark would see the connection attempt).

Comment: thanks all. Will change exception handler first and try that.

Comment: no exception is being caught. Does not seem to be any error within the code. I can ping the ip from command prompt and then tried to do a telnet connection and that failed : could not open connection to the host on port, connect failed. Forgive me if I am confusing networking protocols here but just wanted to try everything

Comment: Print your IP and port. Perhaps you are connecting to the wrong ones (hence nothing in WireShark).

Comment: print shows correct ip and port

Comment: thanks for comments. I ended up not able to solve it and diverted the messages to rabbit queue where the .NET version reads it and sends the message via tcp connection.

Answer (score 2):

Your Java code is not equivalent to your VB.NET code.

---

## Java

Your use of `PrintWriter` does not guarantee UTF-8 encoding:

> `public void println(String x)`
>
> Prints a `String` and then terminates the line. **This method behaves as though it invokes `print(String)`** and then `println()`.

> `public void print(String s)`
>
> Prints a string. If the argument is `null` then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, **the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding**, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

So, you are not guaranteed to be sending UTF-8.  Instead, use `OutputStreamWriter` with a UTF-8 `Charset` assigned to it.

Also, you are sending 2 line terminators, one explicit in the `string` data and one implicit by `println()`.

Try this:

```java
try
{
    clientSocket = new Socket(ipaddress, portnumber);
    clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
    clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);

    outStreamSplunk = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    outStreamSplunk.write(post);
    if (!post.endsWith("\r\n"))
        outStreamSplunk.write("\r\n");
    outStreamSplunk.flush();

    System.out.println("SENT MESSAGE: " + post);

    clientSocket.close();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    // log exc.toString() as needed....
    return;
}
```

---

## VB.NET

The code is forcing UTF-8, and only sends one line terminator.  However, `Environment.NewLine` is platform-specific and not guaranteed to be a `CRLF`, so use `vbCrLf` instead.

Also, using `IPAddress.Parse()` to parse the result of `AddressList(0).ToString()` is redundant overhead since `AddressList(0)` returns an `IPAddress` to begin with, so just use it as-is.

Also, if `Dns.GetHostEntry()` or `initialize()` fails, you are not catching the exception to log it.

Try this:

```vb
'ip = "xxx.xxx.x.xxx"
'port = xxxx

Try
    _GLOIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).AddressList(0)
    _port = port

    'initiate the client and get the stream to use
    myTcp = New TcpClient(New IPEndPoint(_GLOIP, _port))
    netStream = myTcp.GetStream() 

    Dim bufStream As BufferedStream = New BufferedStream(netStream)

    Dim sendBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)
    bufStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    If Not text.EndsWith(vbCrLf) Then
        sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vbCrLf)
        bufStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
    End If

    bufStream.Flush()

Catch ex As Exception
    appLogs.constructLog(err & vbNewLine & ex.Message.ToString, True, True)
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

Alternatively, you could use the `TcpClient` constructor that accepts a string as input and not call `Dns.GetHostEntry()` at all:

```vb
'ip = "xxx.xxx.x.xxx"
'port = xxxx

_GLOIP = ip
_port = port

...

'initiate the client and get the stream to use
myTcp = New TcpClient(_GLOIP, _port)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your flush is in the wrong place. It should be after the write, not before it, where it is completely pointless. Actually you should just close the writer instead of the socket: that wil flush the writer and close the socket. At present the data is never getting out of the writer into the socket.